# Cron job from 9am to 5pm EVERY day

Tags: javascript, cron, schedule, cron-task

I wrote a schedule/cron job with the following expression

`"0 9-17 * * *"`

as I wanted it to run everyday from 9am to 5pm, every hour.
However the callback function was only executed for day 1 and not for everyday.

```
const job = schedule.scheduleJob("0 9-17 * * *", async () => {
// my code
})
```

Please do highlight my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

this should help you with the issue -> https://cron.help/every-5-minutes-between-9-and-5

If you want cronjob to run everyday between 9 to 5 and lets say each 5 miuntes it would be like this:

```
*/5 9-17 * * *
```

If you want to run it every minutes you should do something like:

```
*/1 9-17 * * *
```

To run it between 9-17 each hour use:

```
*/60 9-17 * * *
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to run it with an hour gap like first at 9 am then at 10 am then 11am and so on till 5pm